# Bash script failing when run via cron, can't find Libboost library

Tags: bash, boost, cron

I am running a bash script that uses libboost to hold a statistical model in memory. When I run the script directly from the command line (ie: # /pylda/exec-test.sh) it works fine. However, when it runs on the cron job, I get the following error:

```
"/root/pylda/src/infer: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

How does cron behave differently? Is there an environmental variable that needs to be set? This is cron as root, as far as I know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

As a general comment, don't rely on the presence of environmental variables that you normally have during an interactive (login) session when you cron() a script.  Some implementations define a minimal environment only.  You will do well to include everything you need within your script, either by direct declaration therein or by sourcing a file of the variables you need into it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is old, I think this answer may help others.

Here a sample line of my crontab:

```
0 3 * * 1,2,4,5,6 (. /home/oracle/.profile; export ORACLE_SID=myDB;. myscript.ksh parm1 parm2; ) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Which:
Execute the profile of my user (oracle), so I am sure I have the good envs:. /home/oracle/.profile
Set a local env value: export ORACLE_SID=myDB
Executes the script with its params:. myscript.ksh parm1 parm2 (nota: the dot because the script does not have the x flag)
Does not send email: 1>/dev/null 2>&1 (My script sends the needed emails with formatting).

Use () to enclose a list of commands, and semicolon (;) to separate commands.

Hoping that this can help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the PATH var on Cron script

```
# /etc/cron.d/something
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge on this one - is there a path that would be specific on a CentOS install?

Comment: The answer @michael-krelin-hacker provided is more accurate, you should set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but still you should do that inside your Cron script. You should check your current LD_LIBRARY_PATH with 'env'.